# How to add -fix option to .clang-tidy file?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

```
Checks: 'modernize-use-auto, modernize-use-nullptr, modernize-loop-convert'

CheckOptions:
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.MinConfidence
    value:           safe
```

I have a configration file like this and want to add `-fix` flag to apply possible fixes but I couldn't figure out where exactly place it. Is it possible to add `-fix` or `-fix-errors` flags to `.clang-tidy` file?

Answer (score 5):

`-fix` and `-fix-errors` are not check options but rather command-line options and can not be configured separately for checks.
The available configuration options for `.clang-tidy` files are stated in the [Clang-tidy documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) and the `-fix` option is not there:

```
$ clang-tidy -dump-config
---
Checks:          '-*,some-check'
WarningsAsErrors: ''
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
FormatStyle:     none
User:            user
CheckOptions:
  - key:             some-check.SomeOption
    value:           'some value'
...
```

If you want to run your configuration with the `-fix` option enabled just add it to the command you're running `clang-tidy` from.